# Why isn't this inverse RegEx match working in Visual Studio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2005

I have a RegEx:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item\(\"((?!foo).)*\"
```

that works in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and matches the **second** of the two strings as expected:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("foo")
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("bar")
```

however, if I run the same expression in Visual Studio 2005 - I get no matches. It actually should match every single instance where `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item...` exists because none of them match the word `foo`.

**Unless of course the inverse expression doesn't work in Visual Studio.**

If that's true, how would I go about getting the same result in Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: I don't know VisualStudio but [negative lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) isn't implemented in many Regex engines.

Comment: @dystroy, I wondered. It's one of those things that is an edge case for the implementers I guess and so they get it done if they get around to it. I'm sure it's quite complex.

Comment: @dystroy It is in .NET. And it actually is – to some extent – in most modern regex engines. Fixed-length assertions, as used here, are almost universally supported. /EDIT Ah, this is about the search&replace function in VS. Then all bets are off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex below is adapted from the syntax of [regular expression for find and replace feature in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which is **not the usual Perl-based regex syntax**.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item\("(~(foo).)*"
```

`~(pattern)`, according to the description:

> ```
> Prevent match    ~(X)    Prevents a match when X appears at this point 
>                          in the expression. For example, real~(ity) matches 
>                          the "real" in "realty" and "really," but not the
>                          "real" in "reality."
> ```

Should work similar to how negative look-ahead `(?!pattern)` works.

Comment: Fantastic answer, this worked exactly as I expected! I can mark as the answer in 7 minutes.